# Не удаётся установить библиотеку lxml в python

Tags: python, парсер, библиотеки, lxml

PS E:\PyProjects> pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [74 lines of output]
Building lxml version 4.9.1.
Building without Cython.
Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
copying src\lxml\isoschematron_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes_*init*_.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [76 lines of output]
Building lxml version 4.9.1.
Building without Cython.
Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
running install
C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
copying src\lxml\isoschematron_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes_*init*_.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: Скачайте и установите.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста уточнить немого для чего нужно установить его, как я понял это устанавливает обычный vs для с++, но я же использую vs code для питона

Comment: Это нужно для сборки модулей, lxml написан не на чистом Python, а использует C++, вот для этого и нужен сборщик.

Comment: Файл Python с расширением PYD и есть результат работы сборщика, может иногда быть с расширением DLL. Но это другая история.

Comment: И я не понимаю почему вы задаёте такой вопрос я вам просто продублировал сообщение которое находится в логе. Посмотрите внимательно в ЛОГ. Там уже содержится решение этой проблемы.